Component is not getting rendered correctly in react
I am new to react and I am just trying to create a simple form.
When username and password are entered, and the submit button is clicked. I want a message to be displayed after the form containing username which is not working.
Please help!
import './App.css';
import { Button, Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMessage(<h1>{username}</h1>)
    // console.log('message is ', message)
  }
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>
            Username
          </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={username} onChange={(event) => {
            setUsername(event.target.value)
            console.log(username)
          }} />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>
            Password
          </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={password} onChange={(event) => {
            setPassword(event.target.value)
            console.log(password)
          }} />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button className='mt-3'>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
      {message}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App;
`


This site isn’t for general code troubleshooting questions, but rather for specific technical questions. If you have no idea at all why your program isn’t working—if you haven’t made any progress in troubleshooting it, it’s probably too early to ask a question on SO.

Also this isn’t a react question it’s a react-bootstrap question as the answers show.

Two things you need to check:

The Button in your form should have a type="submit" to trigger the form submission when clicked.
If the message is set before displaying it to avoid showing an empty message initially.

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
            value={username} 
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)} 
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
            type="password" // Ensure password input is hidden
            value={password} 
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} 
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit" className='mt-3'>Submit</Button> {/* Ensure button triggers form submission */}
      </Form>
      {message && <h1>{message}</h1>} {/* Conditionally display the message */}
    </Container>
  );
}



Happy to hear it! Please mark the answer as accepted, so others don't spend time on the problem.

import { Button, Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Username:", username);
    console.log("Password:", password);

    setMessage(`Submitted Username: ${username} and Password: ${password}`);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            value={username}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setUsername(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setPassword(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit" className="mt-3">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;

You can do something like this. I'd suggest read the documentation thoroughly before working: https://react.dev/learn

this part is wrong:
  function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setMessage(<h1>{username}</h1>)
      // console.log('message is ', message)
    }

instead put:
    function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setMessage(`Welcome, ${username}!`); // Sets the message with the username
    }

and the Button should be type submit:
 <Button type="submit">Submit</Button> 

